# Python Pandas: for a multi-indexed dataframe, how to interchange row and one indexed column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas multi-indexed dataframe like the one follows:

```
               col1  col2
    ind1 ind2            
    A    x        3     2
         y        2     0
    B    x        2     4
         y        2     3
    C    x        3     1
         y        0     0
```

Now I want to put the ind2 (x, y) as columns and col1 and col2 as the second-level index, like follows:

```
                     x     y
    ind1 col            
    A    col1        3     2
         col2        2     0
    B    col1        2     4
         col2        2     3
    C    col1        3     1
         col2        0     0
```

I've tried several methods but all failed, is there any easy way to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `df.stack().unstack('ind2')`

Comment: this works, thanks a lot!

Comment: It actually doesn't give the same resulting dataframe that you wanted. Did you make a mistake with the resulting dataframe data?

Comment: no it doesn't, but i redefined the index names after performing df.stack(), then i do unstack('ind2') on the resulting dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky way of doing this. Since your are basically replacing the names of columns with indices you can manually grab the column and index names and then switch them.

```
# grab column and index names
col_names = df.columns.values
idx_names = df.index.levels[1].values

# replace them and then rename the inner index
df.index.set_levels(col_names, level=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = idx_names
df.index.set_names('col', level=1, inplace=True)

          x  y
ind1 col       
A    col1  3  2
     col2  2  0
B    col1  2  4
     col2  2  3
C    col1  3  1
     col2  0  0
```